# How can I disable the "Make your voice heard. Take the 2019 Developer Survey now"-banner

Tags: bug, notifications, survey

This banner pops up every day I open Stack Overflow. I participated in the survey, yet it still asks me again. When I click it even told me to go away because I already did it.

Comment: Have you clicked the "X" on the right hand side to close the notice?

Comment: Yes. I did that yesterday, after it told me to go away. Today it appeared again. If it is so smart to notice that I already did it, why is it even displaying it.

Comment: Are you allowing cookies on SO? I dismissed it and it's never come back.

Comment: I'd suggest testing on a different (up-to-date) browser with cookies enabled. I have never had problems with that banner.

Comment: It literally told you to go away? That is not very welcoming.

Comment: seems like a fair question.  why is it down voted so much?  I agree that this is  a quality of service bug to reprompt for a completed task.

Answer (score 5):

As said by TheWanderer, **this is not a bug** but has something to do with the cookies in your browser.

When you click on the `X` at the right side of the banner, there's a cookie being set in your browser with the name: `ds-notice`. Which will remember whether you closed it or not.

When viewing the cookies in edge, it looks like this:

[image]

Enabling cookies will most likely solve your issue and remember to keep the banner hidden when you close it.

[Enabling cookies in Edge.](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-enable-cookies-edge-browser)

[Enabling cookies in Chrome.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[Enabling cookies in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences)